# creating forms with multiple entry fields

Tags: wpf, forms, c#-4.0, webforms, data-entry

I hope to create an entry form that provides multiple entry fields like it appears in microsoft excel where the column headers are up there and several rows below for data input.

i know textboxes have to be placed one at a time  and only accept one input per text box and that would take awfully long to just create a form with probably just 10 rows and 10 columns.

how do i go about this.?is there any tool from the toolbox that can help design this form? Id also like to pass entries from the form into the database all in one shot so id appreciate it if the control supports that too...

this is a picture of what id like the form to look like...
[image]

Please help out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) would be appropriate?

Comment: I know they are good to display data from your database but i dont know if it would fit entry forms...am trying it out now and not sure which field type i should select...any recommendations?

Comment: Hi Alan...I did try it with DataGridView but like i had expected, it only allows viewing and editing of data that must be bound to it, not entry which i wish to do. could you suggest anything else? for multiple entry fields on forms??